# L1 regularisation in cplex

Tags: convex-optimization, convex

I am trying to perform optimization which uses the L1 regularisation method.

However, I am using cplex and I do not see an obvious way of performing L1 regularisation when I use cplex. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Let me start with the example [curve fitting](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/modelbuilding/blob/master/curvefitting.mod) from [Model Building](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/model-building-oplcplex-alex-fleischer/)

Without regularization:

```
int n=...;
range points=1..n;
float x[points]=...;
float y[points]=...;



// y== b*x+a

dvar float a;
dvar float b;

minimize sum(i in points) (b*x[i]+a-y[i])^2;

subject to
{

}

execute
{
writeln("b=",b);
writeln("a=",a);
}
```

The Lasso Version (L1 regularisation) would be:

```
int n=...;
range points=1..n;
float x[points]=...;
float y[points]=...;

float lambda=0.1;

// y== b*x+a

dvar float a;
dvar float b;

minimize sum(i in points) (b*x[i]+a-y[i])^2+lambda*(abs(a)+abs(b));

subject to
{

}

execute
{
writeln("b=",b);
writeln("a=",a);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, is abs() also supported by the cplex concert technology if I am using c++?

Comment: Yes : IloAbs returns the absolute value of its argument.

Comment: Hi Alex,I am getting an error when I use abs as indicated above. The error says:  No matching function for call to abs. Why is this the case?

Comment: IloAbs returns the absolute value of its argument.

Concert Technology offers predefined functions that return an expression from an algebraic function on expressions. These predefined functions also return a numeric value from an algebraic function on numeric values as well.

IloAbs returns the absolute value of its argument.

What Is Extracted

IloAbs is extracted by an instance of IloCplex and linearized automatically.

Comment: Thank you Alex, it works well.